# rhc ssh [No system SSH available] error

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, ssh-keys, openshift-enterprise

I want view my openshift application log in my cmd.
I did try :
`rhc ssh appname`

that time i am getting:

```
No system SSH available. Please use the --ssh option to specify the path to your SSH executable, or install SSH.
```

My system have already ssh key.so how can i solve that problem?

Comment: It doesn't complain about ssh *keys*, but about the lack of the *executable* ssh. Do you have it in your PATH?

Comment: My ssh file path:"C:\Users\admin\.ssh"

Comment: This folder contain three files.             id_rsa.pub,id_rsa,known_hosts

Comment: That is not an executable, just the folder which contains ssh-related files (keys, config, authorized_keys, known_hosts, ...). I am talking about `ssh.exe`. It should be included in your msysgit distribution. You need to add it to your `%PATH%`.

Comment: I did try to set ssh path using rhc command :rhc ssh -ssh "C:\Users\admin\.ssh" -a appname

Comment: `"C:\Users\admin\.ssh"` is *not* the path of `ssh.exe`.

Comment: I got it your point now i try this?

Comment: I did search ssh.exe in my computer but not found.How can install ssh.exe in my computer.

Comment: Simply install Git (unzip https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.4-preview20140929/PortableGit-1.9.4-preview20140929.7z anywhere you want). ssh.exe is included in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure:

- you are in a cmd session where `HOME` is define (type `set HOME` to check its value: it must be `C:\Users\yourLogin`, because ssh needs to look for keys in `%HOME%\.ssh`)
- your `ssh.exe` parent folder is referenced in the `%PATH%`, or you can type:

  ```
  rhc ssh -ssh "c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.8.3-64-bit\usr\bin\" -a appname
  ```

Replace `c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.8.3-64-bit` with the actual installation path of your Git for Windows.

The easiest solution is to add the `git\usr\bin` folder (which includes `ssh.exe`) to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I am trying :                                                     rhc ssh --ssh "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin" -a appname        but i get message:SSH executable 'C:\Program' does not exist.

Comment: Unzip Git in a path without any space in it. That will be easier.

Comment: I did try this:                                                   rhc ssh --ssh "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Git\bin" -a appname            but i get same error.so i will try msysgit.

Comment: I mean, unzip it in a different path, without space. I suspect "`C:\ProgramFiles(x86)`" doesn't exist. You can use any path you want: `c:\git` for instance.

Comment: @nmkkannan maybe it requires the full path to the exe, not its parent folder. Can you try: `rhc ssh -ssh "c:\git\bin\ssh.exe" -a appname` (replace '`c:\git`' with the path where you unzip git)

Comment: I am adding environment variable HOME ="git_path" without bin folder and path ="***';%HOME%\bin"  It's working fine.          thanks for helping..

Comment: @nmkkannan Great. I have completed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

If you installed Git for Windows<sup>1</sup>, then you can try something similar to:

#### `rhc ssh --ssh C:\PROGRA~1\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe -a <appname>`

e.g.

```
rhc ssh --ssh C:\PROGRA~1\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe -a myawesomeapp
```

---

*Notes*

1. See https://git-scm.com/download/win or https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Comment: See comment left for you as an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36470499/1677912

Comment: actually this saved my day <rhc ssh --ssh C:\PROGRA~1\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe -a appname>

Answer (score 2):

If you are not interested in adding your git path to `PATH` you will need to use a 8.3 style path because rhc can't seem to handle spaces in the path.

- For x86 versions of git use `rhc ssh myapp --ssh C:\Progra~2\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`
- For x64 versions of git use `rhc ssh myapp --ssh "C:\Progra~1\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`

If you leave the spaces like `C:\Users\me>rhc ssh myapp --ssh "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe"`

You will get the following error:

```
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
Connecting to my0apps0guid@myapp-me.rhcloud.com ...
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/ssh.rb:49:in 'exec': No such file or directory - C:\Prog
ram (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/ssh.rb:49:in 'run'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:294:in 'execute'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in 'block (3 levels) in to_commander'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in 'call'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in 'call'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in 'run'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/runner.rb:421:in 'run_active_command'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:72:in 'run!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/delegates.rb:12:in 'run!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in 'start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in '<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/rhc:23:in 'load'
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/rhc:23:in '<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Install 'SSH' client like Cygwin.

A very interesting Tutorial is->>> [nawab-how-to-install-ssh](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first got to **Openshift Web Console >> Settings** and delete the exiting **keys**.  Then run `rhc setup` in command line.  Then try `rhc ssh -a yourApp --ssh C:\PROGRA~1\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`.  This is what worked for me so am sharing this answer.  Hope this helps.  Good Luck.