# Where to see console log in Openshift?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, console, openshift

Recently, I've deployed my JSP project into Openshift server. Now my wish is to see the Console log.

Suppose, if I print `System.out.println("Message");` into my JSP project, how do I see that message printed into Console log in Openshift server?

***EDITED:***

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rajendra @ http://code-programmersplace.rhcloud.com/
  (uuid: 54d19a5be0b8cd9bf9000082)
-------------------------------------------------
  Domain:     programmersplace
  Created:    Feb 04  9:34 AM
  Gears:      1 (defaults to small)
  Git URL:    ssh://54d19a5be0b8cd9bf9000082@code-programmersplace.rhcloud.com/~/gi
t/rajendra.git/
  SSH:        54d19a5be0b8cd9bf9000082@code-programmersplace.rhcloud.com
  Deployment: auto (on git push)

  jbossews-2.0 (Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0))
  ---------------------------------------
    Gears: 1 small

You have access to 1 application.
```

C:\Users\rajendra>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing you need is to connect via SSH to your application on OpenShift. If the name of your app is `awesome`, run the following command:

```
rhc ssh -a awesome
```

If you've forgotten the name of your application, execute `rhc apps` in order to see your current apps. See the lines with something similar to `hereisthename @ http://...` or `.../~/git/hereisthename.git/`.

Once you're connected via SSH, you can see the log using the `tail` command:

- Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)

  ```
  tail -f -n 100 app-root/logs/jbossews.log
  ```
- JBoss Application Server 7

  ```
  tail -f -n 100 app-root/logs/jbossas.log
  ```

The OpenShift Client Tools are required. See [*Installing the OpenShift Client Tools*](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-client-tools.html). See also [*Getting Started with OpenShift Online*](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-overview.html).

---

<sup>RELATED: **[rhc ssh [No system SSH available] error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143724/rhc-ssh-no-system-ssh-available-error)**</sup>

Comment: Sir, But when i run this command `tail -f -n 100 app-root/logs/rajendra.log` .. It says `No such files or directory` What's that mean? :(

Comment: Yes, I'm using Tomcat 7 and `jbossews-2.0 (Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0))` I small gear

Comment: What did you see if use the commands `ls` and `cd`. e.g. `cd app-root/logs/` and `ls`

Comment: It says with `cd` ..`jbossews.log    jbossews.log-20150207071052` `jbossews.log-20150204112733    jbossews.log-20150209082751` ..

Comment: `jbossews.log` is the default name for Tomcat 7 EWS 2 and `jbossas.log` for JBoss 7. :-)

Comment: It's saying `Cannot open '100' for reading: no such file or directory`.. :(

Comment: Sorry! Must be:  `tail -f -n 100 app-root/logs/jbossews.log`. Was a typo! >.<

Comment: Sir, Still getting this error: `tail: cannot open `app-root/logs/jbossews.log` for reading: No such file or directory.. :(

Comment: Return to the home directory with `cd ~`

Comment: hahaha....thanks ..Finally i can see the log .. Really. Thanks for giving me your graceful time :)