# Install RHC Client Tools (Openshift) on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, git, windows-10, openshift-client-tools

Maybe I am missing something, but when trying to install RHC client tools under Windows 10 OS (brandly installed), I got a lot of errors (I never had on Windows 7 or Mac). To anyone who is facing the same issues, it only worked with the following configuration:

**Git:** 1.9.5.msysgit.0

**Ruby:** 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) i386-mingw32

- Both installers are for 32bit processor (installed on a Surface 3 64-bit with Windows 10). 64bit versions didn't work.
- No need to update net-ssh -v2.9.3.beta1package (as suggested when installing other versions).

After installation, rhc commands work without errors.

```
rhc setup
rhc ssh <app>
...
```

Did anyone face the same problem? Is there anything I need to consider? The versions I am using are quite old and I am not very fancy on using old versions with the latest OS update...

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting?

Comment: I had different errors (depending on the installations)... the one mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import, then problems with ssh (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143724/rhc-ssh-no-system-ssh-available-error), although the ssh executable path was added on windows 10... There were multiple errors. Did anyone succeed to run RHC on Windows 10 with the latest versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Windows 10 PC. And I have used newer version of `Ruby` and latest version of `Git`. Please consider viewing the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import/35231025#35231025).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In answer to #laurapons question about running on windows 10. After much frustration I think I solved it by just changing the CMD window properties.
Simply select the 'Use Legacy console' on the Options tab. (To find it right click the top left corner of the CMD window and select properties)