# OpenShift setup invalid argument

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openshift

I've been following [getting started](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html) of openshift, but I am stuck at this error.

```
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace, and check that other programs like Git
are properly installed.

If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just hit enter to use the server for OpenShift Online:
openshift.redhat.com.
Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com| C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/highline-1.6.21/lib/highline.rb:86
4:in `gets': Invalid argument - <STDIN> (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/highline-1.6.21/lib/highline.rb:864:in `get_line'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/highline-1.6.21/lib/highline.rb:885:in `get_response'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/highline-1.6.21/lib/highline.rb:260:in `ask'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <c
lass:HighLineExtension>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:188:in `block in server_stage'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:190:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:190:in `section'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:204:in `paragraph'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:339:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Helpe
rs>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:185:in `server_stage'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:67:in `block in run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:65:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:65:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/setup.rb:57:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:294:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander
'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/runner.rb:421:in `run_active_command'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:72:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/delegates.rb:12:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

I tried reinstalling ruby (and rhc gem) to older version (1.93) as found in a different question. It probably isn't what has been causing my error. I tried using defauld windows commandline and PowerShell 5.0 with the same result.

I am expecting a promp for server hostname, but this stacktrace happens right after entering 'rhc setup'.

Comment: Try Ruby 2.0.0. I just installed it on win 7.

Comment: for some reason, 64bit 2.0 works, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried everything nothing worked except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34546532/5806017) which says "change the CMD window properties. Simply select the 'Use Legacy console'" and It really worked

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.0 64bit worked for some reason

previously the error was evoked by anything with

```
    raw_answer = @input.gets
```

I (and people I've asked) have to classify this as 'Windows Magic'. Windows are such a good development enviroment.

Comment: Thanks very much. "Windows Magic" totally agreed. I am on Win10. Tryied the latest Ruby 2.2.4 but didn't work, found a link on so for the [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import) then the accepted answer leads me to install ssh, but didn't work. another answer saying try the version documented 1.9.3 p194, then it gave me the error and google found me this one.